# Using take(n) more than once on Random sequence

Tags: java, random, sequence, totallylazy

I would like to take groups of strings from a Randomized sequence. I found that Randoms.takeFromValues provides a sequence that is most suitable for this. But it does not quiet work as expected. I am sure there is something I am not doing right. Here is a test code, It fails at second assertion as the size of list2 is 2 instead of 3.

```
@Test
public void totallylazy_random_sequence_test() {
    List<String> strings = list("string-1","string-2","string-3","string-4","string-5","string-6");
    Sequence<String> selector = Randoms.takeFromValues(strings);
    List<String> list1 = selector.take(3).toList();
    List<String> list2 = selector.take(3).toList();
    assertThat(list1.size(), is(3));
    assertThat(list2.size(), is(3));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of TL are you using? As I think this might be caused by this older bug:

https://github.com/bodar/totallylazy/issues/15

Comment: Hey Dan, thanks for this. I upgraded to the latest version and it fixed. I was using 1.72. Although this upgrade forced me to also upgrade utterlyidle but not a biggi, all is up to date and working. Thanks for your help and the awesome library